# How to resize dlib neural network hidden layers at runtime?

Tags: c++, neural-network, dlib

In [dlib](http://dlib.net/) you can construct a neural network as shown in [this example](http://dlib.net/dnn_introduction_ex.cpp.html). It utilizes `using` to define its structure, then create an instance of it like this:

```cpp
using net_type = [...] ;
net_type net;
```

After that point how can a hidden layer be added, removed or resized *at runtime*? There are things like [`add_layer`](http://dlib.net/ml.html#add_layer), but neural nets in dlib are heavily templated and I dont't know, if and how `add_layer` or maybe [`layer`](http://dlib.net/ml.html#layer) to access layers might help.

To be more specific, given the linked example, how would I change, say, the

```
relu<fc<84,
```

part at runtime to, say `relu<fc<100,`, remove it or add another one between any given two layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add layers at runtime.  You can however edit their properties, like the `fc` layer has a `set_num_outputs()`.  Each layer object has documentation you can look at to see what you can do with it.  The docs for `fc` are here: http://dlib.net/dlib/dnn/layers_abstract.h.html#fc_

[This example](http://dlib.net/dnn_introduction2_ex.cpp.html) shows how to access layers. e.g. `layer<7>(net).layer_details().set_num_outputs(123)`.